# ESlint configuration conflicts in Nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js, eslint, visual-studio-code

OS: Linux Ubuntu 20.04.2
So I created my Nuxt.js project and the code is failed to compile.

[image: ESLintError]

But there's no any problem in the VSCode:
[image: VSCode]

Why is this happening?
I do not want to ignore errors. I want them to be auto-fixed and so the code would compile without errors.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem has been solved this way:

1. I erased and re-create the whole project (perhaps I screwed a bit with settings and the project was empty, so it was faster and easier to just re-install it, rather than trying to fix all the settings);
2. Create `.vscode/settings.json` in project folder;
3. Placed this into `./vscode/settings.json`:

```
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "vetur.validation.template": false,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
  }
}
```

And voila, everything works just fine.